# Need a help in understanding a proof of a lemma.

Tags: induction, proof-explanation

The lemma and part of the proof is given in the following picture:

[image]

I could not understand how the basis case is proved, could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: I wonder: what was the definition of "$\lvert \alpha_k\rvert\to 0$"?... At a certain age it is hard to recall.

Comment: it means the absolute value of alpha converges to 0 for every k@G.Sassatelli

Comment: That isn't a definition. It is just another name (a wrong one, specifically, because the string "for every k" should be substituted with the empty string).

Comment: we are in analysis not computer science and the $k \in N$.@G.Sassatelli

Comment: The first step is basically the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\alpha_k|\to 0,$ therefore, by definition ocrresponding to each $\epsilon >0,$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $|\alpha_k|<\epsilon$ for all $k \geq n_0.$

In particular, taking $\epsilon =|\beta_1|>0$ and $k_1 = n_0$ you get $|\alpha_{k_1}| < |\beta_1|.$